# константы для аттрибутов Model

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

При использовании Spring mvc, мы в Model передаём необходимые значения в аттрибуты, чтоб потом отобразить их на странице.
В методе контролёра:

```
model.addAttribute("name", myName);
```

на странице html:

```
<title th:text="${name}"></title>
```

Потенциальный баг - изменить имя атрибута в контролёре и забыть это сделать на страничке html.
Это можно решить создав спец класс для хранения этих атрибутов.
Для контролёра это будет выглядеть так:

```
model.addAttribute(CommonAttributes.NAME, myName);
```

таким образом, если необходимо изменить имя атрибута, то мы его меняем только в одном месте - CommonAttributes.NAME, это отлично сработает для жава классов.
Как создать что то подобное для классов и страничек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете класс (не интерфейс!!!), в котором будут все ваши константы, например, `CommonAttributes.java`, в нем описываете константы, например, `public static final String NAME = "name";`
В `jsp`-файле вначале описываете импорт `<%@ page import="CommonAttributes" %>`.
Использование: например, `<input type="text" id="inputName" name="${Parameters.NAME}">`. Ну и в сервлете уже ваш код `model.addAttribute(CommonAttributes.NAME, myName);`

Как-то так. У меня так работает.